# How to draw UIBezier path for Custom views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a **UIView** which contains a stack of subviews. I want to draw bezier path on the super view. The angle of subviews is dynamic. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

[image: Actual View]

[image: Expected output]

Comment: I'm confused. To me, it sounds like all you want is to draw a `UIBezierPath` on the superview. So why not do that? Is there some issue you haven't explained?

Comment: When I draw on the superview by giving superview rect to UIBezierPath, the yellow background is visible. @dfd